# Target class shape & type in train_test_split

Tags: python, dataset, scikit-learn

In `train_test_split` function of `sklearn`, what should be the shape & type of the target class? Does it make a difference?

Also, when we give `.shape` command on a data structure, how are the following two different:

1. $(x, )$
2. $(x, 1)$

where $x$ is the dimension?